# how to make function every ...minutes (pyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python, telegram

i need to execute code every x minutes in pyTelegramBotAPI how i need to do it?

```
import telebot
from datetime import timedelta, datetime 
 
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message): 
???
```

Comment: There is a possibility to use 'asyncio', not too sure. But for this you just have a while true function running and a time.sleep(x)

Answer (score 1):

`time.sleep` and `threading` work wonders. Let's say that the audience of your bot is people who constantly forget to buy carrots. And you want to remind them every minute.

In the following code, the `send_reminder` function sends a reminder to all bot users every 60 seconds (the variable `delay` is responsible for the number of seconds). To run the function, we use threading, and to create a delay, we use `time.sleep(delay)`. `threading` is needed so that `time.sleep()` stops only the target function, and not the entire bot.

The function uses an infinite loop, in which the bot first sends reminders to all users from the `ids`, then waits for 1 minute, and everything repeats again.

```
import telebot
import threading
from time import sleep

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
delay = 60  # in seconds
ids = []


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message): 
    global ids
    id = message.from_user.id
    ids.append(id)
    bot.send_message(id, 'Hi!')

def send_reminder():
    global ids
    while True:
        for id in ids:
            bot.send_message(id, 'Buy some carrots!')
        sleep(delay)


t = threading.Thread(target=send_reminder)
t.start()

while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
    except:
        sleep(10)
```